# Wrap <LI> text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap the text within unordered list with `<span>`

Trying this, but it does not seem to work...

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(/^(\w){1}/, "<span>$1</span>");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use jQuery's [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().wrap('<span></span>');       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7HdER/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) method:

```
$('li').wrapInner('<span/>')​​​​​​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UrTw5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = "<span>" + text + "</span>";
    $(this).html(text);
});
```